# Making Private Transactions on the ethereum network

Tags: hash, transactions, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I've been working on a mechanism to make private transactions achievable on the ethereum network using zk-snarks and verifiable hashes.

I took alot of help from an existing work done on this mechanism. below is the link.

https://github.com/EYBlockchain/nightfall

Right now all this is functional on a local chain but when i move it to the geth network, transaction fails.

Any help on how to configure the above mechanism on etheruem network or a test network like rinkeby or ropsten will be highly appreciated.

Comment: whats the error msg you are getting?

Comment: it gives an error of invalid block hash.

Comment: it is not possible, you can't send a Tx to the blockchain and break the whole net.